# How to apply use a function (animate) to only selected class in many classes having same class name

Tags: jquery

```html
 <ul class="paralx-position">
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="2">Accelerate</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div2" id="img2" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="3">Transform</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div3" id="img3" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="1">Build</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" class="Active" data-box="div1"  id="img1"  tabindex="0"><span class="icon-position"><!--<img src="images/logos/noun_build_1909132.svg" class="icon"></img></span></img>--></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="4">Ignite</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div4" id="img4"  tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="5">Develop</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div5" id="img5" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="6">Engineer</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div6" id="img6" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
```

I was doing this animation with css but it had some issues

```
.paralx-dot-1:focus{
    animation-name:bright-dot;
 animation-duration:1.5s;
 height: 24.75px;
 width: 24.75px;
   outline: none;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 


}
@keyframes bright-dot {
 from {transform:scale(1,1);}
 to {transform:scale(2,2);}
}
```

in this css the animation was working fine it only applies to the selected image because of focus property but animation reset when you click anywhere else so i tried the same with Jquery it worked but now its applying to all the selected images insted of only clicked image

```js
$('.paralx-dot-1').on('click', function () {
  $(this).transition({ scale: 1.5 });
});
```

i did the same functionality with Jquery but i want it only applies to selected image (dot) only 
 ( https://ibb.co/PhCZ16f ) in this image you can see it apples to all the selected images where as it should be apply to selected image only

Comment: What's the difference between "all the selected images" and "the selected image only"?  Either one is selected or multiple are selected - what's "selected" even when your code is for "click"

Comment: What other library are you using?  `$(...).transition is not a function`

Comment: as you can see in this image i have six dots ( https://ibb.co/PhCZ16f ) when i am clicking the image/dot the Jquery is doing the transition .. here i clicked on 3 dots 
and they did transition 

The thing is happening is it applies to every selected image and remain as it is 
i want to reset when clicked on another dot and that another dot do transition

Comment: i am using a Jquery plugin

Comment: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ this  one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you are expecting,thanks

```js
$('.paralx-dot-1').on('click', function () {
  $(this).transition({ scale: 1.5 });
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('img').transition({ scale: 1 });
});
```

```css
.paralx-dot-1:focus{
    animation-name:bright-dot;
    animation-duration:1.5s;
    height: 24.75px;
    width: 24.75px;
    outline: none;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes bright-dot {
    from {transform:scale(1,1);};
    to {transform:scale(2,2);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<ul class="paralx-position">
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="2">Accelerate</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div2" id="img2" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="3">Transform</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div3" id="img3" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="1">Build</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" class="Active" data-box="div1"  id="img1"  tabindex="0"><span class="icon-position"><!--<img src="images/logos/noun_build_1909132.svg" class="icon"></img></span></img>--></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="4">Ignite</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div4" id="img4"  tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="5">Develop</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div5" id="img5" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text" id="6">Engineer</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div6" id="img6" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
```